# Click on buttons in DataTemplate - WP8

Tags: c, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm using this datatemplate for my app , which used context menu from WP8 toolkit . So each item in this datatemplate has a button (to open context menu) and context menu also has click events

So when I use this datatemplate for my LongListSelectors in app, how can I call these click events?

```
<DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefenitions>.........
            ......
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Click="openContext" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="false">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Download" 
                                          Click="context_download" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add to later" 
                                          Click="context_later" />
                        .......
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This context menu is meant to be opened with hold on particular item. It is common across the operating system, in this way you could confuse your users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context menu should be declared inside the element and not separately. Declare your context menu inside your button like below code and remove the click event in your button.

Whenever you declare context menu in your button, it works automatically (opens context menu) without any click event.

```
<Button Content="ContextMenu">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Download" Click="context_download"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add to later" Click="context_later"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

Comment: yes , but my question here is when I put all these control (button, grid, contextmenu ...) in a data template, can I use the event handler of this control (here is context_download and context_later ) ?

Comment: Yeah, Why not? Haven't you tried? You can refer this answer for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319007/wpfhow-to-raise-datatemplates-context-menuitem-event